# Steam VR Input Settings resets after hit the play Button

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I try to add Joystick Movement but every Time i delete the old Joystick Input Settings and add the new one it resets after i hit play

It feels like a bug, beacuse it works days before with other Input's (OpenInv and OpenHelp)
There are no Errors in Console
[SteamVR Input Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIZ4f.png)

This is what i want but after i hit play it resets to both side "SnapTurn"
[SteamVR Input Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uGOR.png)

My Unity Version is 2019.2.17f1

Hope anybody can help me and Thank you

Comment: Are you saving the input bindings before hitting play?

Comment: yes i save these input bindings before hitting play

Comment: Where are you using this action? Is it still selected in the inspector (assuming it's a serialized field)? I ask because I just recently had an issue where the action was removed from my prefab object when I edited the input bindings.

Comment: That was my Problem..
now it works for me
I don't set the Binding in a Script.. uff
But its strange i can remember i put a binding before i test it..

Comment: I Set the Binding in the Player Object but there it didn't work, now i bind it in the left hand and it work.